# How To create an anagram of a word?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anagram

how can i make an anagram of a word using random.shuffle? so far I have this this comes up with a error message:any help is very much appreciated:

```
    import random
    word = "house"
    random.shuffle(word)
    print(word)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function shuffle in the random module shuffles in-place, so you first have to convert your string to a list of characters, shuffle it, then join the result again.

```
import random
word = "house"
l = list(word)
random.shuffle(l)
result = ''.join(l)
print(result)
```

Comment: If the string is pure ASCII, you can also use [`bytearray`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bytearray):  `word_ = bytearray(word, 'ASCII'); random.shuffle(word_); result = word_.decode('ASCII')`